# Why global "this.function" is not accessible without "this."?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
this.func0 = function() {
   console.log('hi')
}
this.func0() // this works
func0() // but not this?
```

Why `func0()` is not working?
Aren't `this.f()` and just `f()` both supposed to access global object?

Comment: What environment are you running this code?

Comment: Works for me in the chrome console...

Comment: so global is not global sometimes?

Comment: I've tried this on node and the result is as expected.(command prompt 0.8.15)

Comment: I have this exact code that I posted as a contencts of a file `test.js`, then I type `node test.js` and get `func0 is undefined` (node -v 0.10.26)

Answer (score 5):

The important thing to understand here is, in Node.js, each and every JavaScript file will be treated as a separate module.

So, within the JavaScript file, `this` will refer to the current module object, not the `global` object. We have something called [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object in Node.js, which is somewhat similar to browsers' `window` object.

This is what you are doing with your program

```
this.func0 = function() {
   console.log('hi')
}
```

you are creating a function object and assigning it to the current module's `func0` attribute.

```
this.func0();
```

you are calling current module's `func0`.

```
func0();
```

JavaScript, searches for `func0` in the current scope, then in the global scope but it doesn't find it anywhere. That is why it fails with the `ReferenceError`

```
ReferenceError: func0 is not defined
```

If you really wanted to set that in the global scope, then you should do it like this

```
global.func0 = function() {
   console.log('hi')
}
func0();
// hi
```